# Can my work's Wifi see the video I sent through Snapchat

Tags: network, wifi

So I accidentally sent a video over Snapchat at work using my works WiFi on my own personal device. To connect to the WiFi I have to put my work user ID and password in and I’m pretty sure some certificate comes up that has to be downloaded. But there is no software that work makes me download onto my phone. I do work at a state tax agency so privacy and security I imagine are pretty high. Are they able to see the exact video that I sent or will they just see that I sent a video through Snapchat but don’t know what the video is? And is there any cause for them to view the network traffic info/sent video through Snapchat unless it was to some very suspicious address or location which would lead them to looking into the sent Snapchat?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This depends on whether the certificate you downloaded was a root signing certificate or a WPA2 Enterprise certificate. If it's the former, then they can MITM any connection you make.

Comment: @forest How will I know which one it is? Will it say which type of certificate it is when I go to accept the certificate?

Comment: I dunno, ask someone at work? Or try to remember what exactly you downloaded?

Comment: @forest Am I able to just disconnect from the network/forget the network and then sign back in and it will have me download the certificate again?

Comment: I don't know. This depends on your model of phone and I know nothing about phones.

Comment: As a former .gov employee... the notice on the phone that all communications are monitored applies to the network as well............. TLS is only as secure as the CA and the installed certificates.  The only answer to your question is: **Don't expect privacy on your work's network... especially a government network.** .......